# Issue with XML::Bare

Tags: xml, perl

I'm using [XML::Bare](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ecodechild/XML-Bare-0.53/Bare.pm) module in Perl.

My XML is something like:

```
<xml>
    <element num="1">
        <num>10</num>
    </element>
    <element num="2">
        <num>20</num>
    </element>
</xml>
```

I want to extract the value contained in child `<num>` tag. i.e. I want `10 and 20` as output. But, when I get value using `$xml->{element}->[$i]->{num}->{value}`, it returns `1 and 2`; i.e., it returns with value of `num` attribute instead of child node.

Can anyone please help me how to handle cases when attribute and child name are same?

Comment: The data structure used by XML::Simple and XML::Bare can't handle elements with attributes and child elements of the same name because `$ele->{num}` means "the attribute or the children named `num`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [`XML::Bare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aBare) or [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aSimple) are used, they should be limited to only the most basic XML reading.  Given that your data has an attribute and child node that share a name fails that limitation.

In truth though, unless there is a specific reason to not, one should just stick with the more modern XML Parsers such as [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig) and [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML) and the full power of XPath support.

The following parses your XML using both of these two modules:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;
use XML::Twig;

my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

print "XML::LibXML\n";
my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $data);
for my $node ($xml->findnodes('//element/num')) {
    print $node->textContent(), "\n";
}

print "XML::Twig\n";
my $t = XML::Twig->new( 
    twig_handlers => {
        '//element/num' => sub { print $_->text(), "\n" },
    },
);
$t->parse( $data );

__DATA__
<xml>
    <element num="1">
        <num>10</num>
    </element>
    <element num="2">
        <num>20</num>
    </element>
</xml>
```

Outputs:

```
XML::LibXML
10
20
XML::Twig
10
20
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in `XML::Bare`.  I don't see the `<num>` element in `Dumper` output:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Bare;

my $xml = q(
<xml>
    <element num="1">
        <num>10</num>
    </element>
    <element num="2">
        <num>20</num>
    </element>
</xml>
);

my $ob = new XML::Bare( text => $xml );
my $root = $ob->parse();

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;
print Dumper($root);

__END__

$VAR1 = {
          '_i' => 0,
          '_pos' => 0,
          '_z' => 0,
          'value' => '
',
          'xml' => {
                     '_i' => 438404290,
                     '_pos' => 1,
                     '_z' => 130,
                     'element' => [
                                    {
                                      '_i' => 438404300,
                                      '_pos' => 2,
                                      '_z' => 64,
                                      'num' => {
                                                 '_att' => 1,
                                                 'value' => '1'
                                               },
                                      'value' => '
        '
                                    },
                                    {
                                      '_i' => 438404359,
                                      '_pos' => 4,
                                      '_z' => 123,
                                      'num' => {
                                                 '_att' => 1,
                                                 'value' => '2'
                                               },
                                      'value' => '
        '
                                    }
                                  ],
                     'value' => '
    '
                   }
        };
```

[You could submit a bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=XML-Bare).

Here is a solution with `XML::Twig`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = q(
<xml>
    <element num="1">
        <num>10</num>
    </element>
    <element num="2">
        <num>20</num>
    </element>
</xml>
);

my $twig= XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => { element => \&elem });
$twig->parse($xml);

sub elem {
    my( $twig, $ele)= @_;
    my $att = $ele->att('num');
    my $num = $ele->first_child('num')->text();
    print "$att $num\n";
}

__END__

1 10
2 20
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about the same... :)